# Speeding up rotation fluently

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

When I press down 'A' the square is speeding up its own rotation, but when I release 'A' it's rotating fasted than before but looks slower than when pressing 'A'.

```
package backend;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import org.lwjgl.glfw.*;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.*;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.*;

public class runGame {

    private long window;
    private GLFWKeyCallback keyCallback;
    private GLFWErrorCallback errorCallback;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new runGame().run();
    }
    private void run()  {
        try {
            init();
            loop();
            glfwDestroyWindow(window);
            keyCallback.release();
        } finally {
            glfwTerminate();
        }
    }
    private static final int width = 640;
    private static final int height = 480;
    private void init() {
        glfwSetErrorCallback(errorCallback);
        if(glfwInit() != GL11.GL_TRUE) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW");
        }
        glfwDefaultWindowHints();
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GL_FALSE);
        //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

        window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "mazeRunner Game", 0, 0);
        if (window == NULL)
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create the GLFW window");
        glfwSetKeyCallback(window, keyCallback = new GLFWKeyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void invoke(long window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
                if( key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_RELEASE ) {
                    glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
                }
                if( key == GLFW_KEY_A && action == GLFW_PRESS ) {
                    speedUp = true;
                }
                if( key == GLFW_KEY_A && action == GLFW_RELEASE ) {
                    speedUp = false;
                }
            }
        });
        ByteBuffer glfwvidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
        glfwSetWindowPos(window, 
                (GLFWvidmode.width(glfwvidmode)-width)/2,
                (GLFWvidmode.height(glfwvidmode)-height)/2);
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        glfwSwapInterval(1);
        glfwShowWindow(window);



        GLContext.createFromCurrent();
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        float aspect_ratio = ((float)height) / width;
        glFrustum(.5, -.5, -.5 * aspect_ratio, .5 * aspect_ratio, 1, 50);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    }
    private final double fps = 60.0f;
    private double time;
    private void loop() {
        time = glfwGetTime();
        while(glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == GL_FALSE) {
            if(glfwGetTime()-time>=1/fps) { 
                glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
                time = glfwGetTime(); draw(); 
                glfwSwapBuffers(window);
                glfwPollEvents();
            }
        }
    }

    private void draw() {
        glLoadIdentity();
        glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f);
        if(speedUp==true) speed = speed+0.9f;
        drawSquare(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    }

    boolean speedUp;
    private float speed = 20.0f;
    private void drawSquare(float red,float green,float blue) {
        glRotatef(speed*(float)time, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);      // Draw The Cube Using quads
        {
            glColor3f(red, green, blue);
            glVertex2f(0, 0);
            glColor3f(red * .8f, green * .8f, blue * .8f);
            glVertex2f(0, 1);
            glColor3f(red * .5f, green * .5f, blue * .5f);
            glVertex2f(1, 1);
            glColor3f(red * .8f, green * .8f, blue * .8f);
            glVertex2f(1, 0);
        }
        glEnd();            // End Drawing The Cube
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with different speed is related to the way you are handling the time. The variable 'time' will contain the total time since the program start when you calculate the rotation angle.

```
glRotatef(speed*(float)time, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

This means that the speed difference is applied not just to the current frame but all previous frames since the program start as well. This is the reason why the rotation is faster than expected when pressing 'a' key.

It's easy to verify this. If you press 'a' directly when the program starts and you see that the speed difference is minimal. Now wait a minute or so and press 'a' again. Now the speed difference is much higher since the accumulated time is higher.

To solve the problem you probably should change the rotation calculation so that the frame time is used instead of the total program time. I.e. store the current rotation angle in a variable which you increase each frame based on the speed and frame time.